# SQL SELECT CASE WITH SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

I have this situation on my DB MySQL:

> TABLE_A
>   Cod | Value1 | Value2 |Value3
>
> TABLE_B
>   Cod | Value4 | Value5
>
> TABLE_C
>   Cod | Value6

And I use this query:

```
SELECT
  table_a.value1 AS Number, 
  table_a.value2 AS Date, 
  table_b.name   AS Name, 
  table_b.age    AS Age 
FROM 
  table_a 
  LEFT JOIN table_c 
         ON table_a.cod = table_c.cod 
            AND table_c.value5 = 1 
  LEFT JOIN table_b 
         ON table_c.cod = table_b.cod 
WHERE value3 = 'MY_SEARCH_VALUE' 
ORDER BY table_a.cod ASC
```

All works great, but now I must select elements from TABLE_A (join with TABLE_B and TABLE_C) connect with one element on TABLE_A.

For example when `TABLE_A.Cod = 'X'` then select also `TABLE_A.Cod ='Y'` and `TABLE_A.Cod ='Z'` on the contrary when `TABLE_A.Cod = 'ALL_OTHERS_CODE'` use the query above.

---

**Edit**: (*Added from OP's comments below*):

The results of my query

```
SELECT
  TABLE_A.Value1 AS Number,
  TABLE_A.Value2 AS Date,
  TABLE_B.name AS Name,
  TABLE_B.age AS Age
FROM
  TABLE_A
  LEFT JOIN TABLE_C
         ON TABLE_A.Cod = TABLE_C.Cod
            AND TABLE_C.Value5 =1
  LEFT JOIN TABLE_B
         ON TABLE_C.Cod = TABLE_B.Cod
WHERE Value3 = 'DEFENDER'
ORDER BY TABLE_A.Cod ASC
```

is for example: (`12` - `14/01/01` - `John` - `18`)

I want the result to be more like the one above. If I should try another code for example `'DEFENDER_A'` and I expect to have: (`12`, `14/01/01`, `John`, `18` --- `5`, `14/01/01`, `Frank`, `19`)

Comment: Your requirements are unclear.  Please use sample data and example results to demonstrate your requirements and any known edge cases.

Comment: The results of my query (SELECT TABLE_A.Value1 AS Number,
       TABLE_A.Value2 AS Date,
       TABLE_B.name AS Name,
       TABLE_B.age AS Age
FROM TABLE_A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_C ON TABLE_A.Cod = TABLE_C.Cod
AND TABLE_C.Value5 =1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_C.Cod = TABLE_B.Cod
WHERE Value3 = 'DEFENDER'
ORDER BY TABLE_A.Cod ASC is for example: (12 - 14/01/01 - John - 18)

Comment: I want the result to be more like the one above if I should try another code for example 'DEFENDER_A' and I expect to have: (12,14/01/01,John,18 --- 
5,14/01/01,Frank,19)

Comment: The requirements are vague. Please provide sample date so thatwould be helpful to provide solutions

Comment: I wanna connect select of one element in TABLE_A with other in the same table and the result have to show the 4 field.

Comment: One missing piece : sample input that will give that output

Answer (score 2):

change your code like this.

```
Select
TABLE_A.Value1 AS Number, 
TABLE_A.Value2 AS Date, 
TABLE_B.name AS Name, 
TABLE_B.age AS Age 
FROM TABLE_A LEFT JOIN TABLE_C ON TABLE_A.Cod = TABLE_C.Cod 
AND TABLE_C.Value5 =1 LEFT JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.Cod = TABLE_B.Cod 
WHERE Value3 = 'DEFENDER' 
ORDER BY TABLE_A.Cod ASC
```

Comment: The problem isn't JOIN... Now I modify my query with this: 
`SELECT TABLE_A.Value1 AS Number, TABLE_A.Value2 AS Date, TABLE_B.name AS Name, TABLE_B.age AS Age FROM TABLE_A LEFT JOIN TABLE_C ON TABLE_A.Cod = TABLE_C.Cod AND TABLE_C.Value5 =1 LEFT JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_C.Cod = TABLE_B.Cod WHERE Value3 = CASE WHEN  'DEFENDER'
THEN (
 'DEFENDER'
AND  'DEFENDER_A'
AND  'DEFENDER_B'
)
ELSE Value3
END  ORDER BY TABLE_A.Cod ASC`

But the result isn't correct

Comment: Second left join should be TABLE_A.Cod = TABLE_B.Cod. you want to join Table A with Table B . right?

Comment: Yes... TABLE_A is connect to TABLE_B and TABLE_C, TABLE_B and TABLE_C aren't connect between them

Comment: then you should change ON TABLE_A.Cod = TABLE_B.Cod in your second join of your query.

Comment: I don't understand... Why?

Comment: you want to fetch Cod only exist in Table A right? then you have to join Table A with Table B and Table A with Table C.Not Table B with C.

Comment: No I want to show all join but start with table A code... However I solved it in other way in Java code and not with sql.
Thanks